# How to Publish ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application with Entity Framework 6 code first to windows Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I am neu in publishing File to Azure . I use MVC 5. It also uses entity framework 6.I have two DbContext classes. One for my models and the other for the Identity models.I have created a new Windows Azure Website and linked an SQL database to it.I have downloaded my publish profile which I have used to publish my site. I see both contexts on the settings tab of the Publish Web dialog box. I have selected the appropriate database from the list available for each of my contexts, chosen to use the connection string at runtime and enabled Execute Code First Migrations for both contexts.

but does not work !

Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

any Idea?

Comment: This has nothing to do with publishing. That's the standard error message for unhandled exceptions. It means your application through an exception that nobody caught so it crashed. You need to add proper logging

Comment: On the other hand, the MVC 5 template includes *both* Azure hosting *and* Application Insights. App Insights gathers statistics *and* information about unhandled exceptions. You should definitely add error handling and logging code though

Comment: I am suspecting issue with the code first migration. It does create trouble some times. If you can try running from your local pointing to the SQL database. If it is SQL azure then you might need to allow connection from your ip.

Comment: @Vijay or it could be a missing file. Or bad credentials. Or, or, or, or. Without exception handling and logging, it's impossible to solve this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree. I did face similar issue last week and tend to check it first.

Comment: thanks , Error Fixed , but still no connection between my Local Database and Azure Database ... what should I do ?

Comment: check you actual web config (in azure) for connection string using kudu by navigation to: Debug console -> CMD -> Site -> wwwroot -> web.config(edit icon)